# Why does ValidForm Builder not work with my addConditions?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, validform

The code below shows my attempt to get the `addCondition()` to work with [PHP ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org). The only condition that works is the 3rd condition -- calculations -- and when it does, all 3 conditional form elements appear.

Can ValidForm Builder work on more than 1 condition?

```
  // PRICEMETHOD
  $objWeb = $objGroup->addField('priceMethod', 'Price Method', VFORM_RADIO_LIST,
    array('required' => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? false : true)),
    array('required' => 'Price Method is required'),
    array(
      'fieldclass' => 'vf__inlineButtons',
      'tip' => (($_SESSION['auth']['tips'] && $_POST['action'] != 'delete') ? VFB_TIP_SERVICES_PRICEMETHOD : NULL),
      (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'fieldDisabled' : 'fieldEnabled') => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'),
      'default' => $default['priceMethod']
    )
  );
  $objWeb->addField('Fixed', 'F');
  $objWeb->addField('Percent', 'P');
  $objWeb->addField('Calculation', 'C');

  // PRICERATE CONDITION -- FIXED
  $objFixed = $objGroup->addField('priceRate', 'Price Rate', VFORM_TEXT,
    array(
      'required' => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? false : true),
      'maxLength' => VFB_MAXLENGTH_SERVICES_PRICERATE
    ),
    array('required' => 'Price Rate is required'),
    array(
      'fieldclass' => 'vf__textarea255',
      'tip' => (($_SESSION['auth']['tips'] && $_POST['action'] != 'delete') ? VFB_TIP_SERVICES_PRICERATE : NULL),
      (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'fieldDisabled' : 'fieldEnabled') => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'),
      'default' => $default['priceRate']
    )
  );
  $objFixed->addCondition('visible', true,
    array(new VF_Comparison($objWeb, VFORM_COMPARISON_EQUAL, 'F'))
  );

  // PRICERATE CONDITION -- PERCENT
  $objPercent = $objGroup->addField('priceRate', 'Price Rate', VFORM_TEXT,
    array(
      'required' => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? false : true),
      'maxLength' => VFB_MAXLENGTH_SERVICES_PRICERATE
    ),
    array('required' => 'Price Rate is required'),
    array(
      'fieldclass' => 'vf__textarea255',
      'tip' => (($_SESSION['auth']['tips'] && $_POST['action'] != 'delete') ? VFB_TIP_SERVICES_PRICERATE : NULL),
      (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'fieldDisabled' : 'fieldEnabled') => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'),
      'default' => $default['priceRate']
    )
  );
  $objPercent->addCondition('visible', true,
    array(new VF_Comparison($objWeb, VFORM_COMPARISON_EQUAL, 'P'))
  );

  // PRICERATE CONDITION -- CALCULATION
  $objCalculation = $objGroup->addField('priceRate', 'Price Rate', VFORM_TEXT,
    array(
      'required' => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? false : true),
      'maxLength' => VFB_MAXLENGTH_SERVICES_PRICERATE
    ),
    array('required' => 'Price Rate is required'),
    array(
      'fieldclass' => 'vf__textarea255',
      'tip' => (($_SESSION['auth']['tips'] && $_POST['action'] != 'delete') ? VFB_TIP_SERVICES_PRICERATE : NULL),
      (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'fieldDisabled' : 'fieldEnabled') => (($_POST['action'] == 'delete') ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'),
      'default' => $default['priceRate']
    )
  );
  $objCalculation->addCondition('visible', true,
    array(new VF_Comparison($objWeb, VFORM_COMPARISON_EQUAL, 'C'))
  );
```

*FYI -- what happens inside the condition is being developed and will change. All I need to know and do now is to get multi-criteria conditioning to work, if possible.*

**Behavioral Results**

Option #1 - selecting Fixed
[image]

Option #2 - selecting Percent
[image]

Option #3 - selecting Calculation
[image]

**My Trial & Error Tests:**

1. leaving the addCondition() statements as is in the code block shown above -- **no success**.
2. moving the addCondition() statements below all of the $objGroup->addField() elements -- **no success**.
3. tried changing each compare value -- 'F' to 'Fixed', 'P' to 'Percent', and 'C' to 'Calculation' -- **no success**.
4. tried double-quotes vs. single-quotes [eg., $objCalculation->addCondition("visible", true, array(new VF_Comparison($objWeb, VFORM_COMPARISON_EQUAL, "C")));] -- **no success**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fact that you've named all three fields exactly the same. You should always use unique field names in HTML forms in general and especially in ValidForm Builder due to the fact that it selects fields based on their name (ID).

When you have multiple fields with the same ID, the condition javascript logic is executed on all of these fields, which is exactly what's happening here.

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Comment: Too bad @vfbStudent never gets back here to verify the answers.